# Unused argument error when building a Confusion Matrix in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am currently trying to run Logistic Regression model on my DF.

While I was creating a new `modelframe` with the actual and predicted values i get get the following error message.

```
Error
Error in confusionMatrix(as.factor(log_class), lgtest$Satisfaction, positive = "satisfied") : 
  unused argument (positive = "satisfied")
```

This is my model:

```
    #### Logistic regression model
    log_model = glm(Satisfaction~., data = lgtrain, family = "binomial")
    summary(log_model)
    log_preds = predict(log_model, lgtest[,1:22], type = "response")
    head(log_preds)
    log_class = array(c(99))
    for (i in 1:length(log_preds)){
      if(log_preds[i]>0.5){
        log_class[i]="satisfied"}else{log_class[i]="neutral or dissatisfied"}}
    
    ### Creating a new modelframe containing the actual and predicted values.
    log_result = data.frame(Actual = lgtest$Satisfaction, Prediction = log_class)
    lgtest$Satisfaction = factor(lgtest$Satisfaction, c(1,0),labels=c("satisfied","neutral or dissatisfied"))
    lgtest
    
    confusionMatrix(log_class, log_preds, threshold = 0.5) ####this works 

    mr1 = confusionMatrix(as.factor(log_class),lgtest$Satisfaction, positive = "satisfied") ## this is the line that causes the error
```

Comment: Hello, confusionMatrix is the function from the caret package ?

Comment: @LeonIpdjian correct it is a function from the caret package I am using version 6.0-86

Comment: Try to replace "labels" parameter by "levels" in your factor. Maybe it will solve your problem.

lgtest$Satisfaction = factor(lgtest$Satisfaction, c(1,0),levels=c("satisfied","neutral or dissatisfied"))

Comment: @LeonIpdjian i tried that but i still have the error when i run
mr1 = confusionMatrix(as.factor(log_class),lgtest$Satisfaction, positive = "satisfied")

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I typed "?confusionMatrix" and take this output:

*Help on topic 'confusionMatrix' was found in the following packages:*

*confusionMatrix
(in package **InformationValue** in library /home/beyza/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6)*

*Create a confusion matrix
(in package **caret** in library /home/beyza/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6)*

*Confusion Matrix
(in package **ModelMetrics** in library /home/beyza/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6)*

As we can understand from here, since it is in more than one package, we need to specify which package we want to use.

So I typed code with "caret::confusionMatrix(...)" and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can write the code to get rid of argument error when building a confusion matrix in R

```
caret::confusionMatrix(
  data = new_tree_predict$predicted,
  reference = new_tree_predict$actual,
  positive = "True"
)
```

Comment: Please provide example code and data to show this fixes the problem. You are referencing an object `new_tree_predict` that the OP's code does not produce and so we cannot verify if this does (not) work and under what conditions it may (not).